# Design and normalization issue : type of FK depends of an other field

Tags: postgresql, database-design, normalization, null

I have a `CapitalIncrease` table, which contains a list of available payment methods. For each payment method, I need to put some data (`SepaDocument` OR `Iban` OR `Crypto`).

Here is a mermaidjs graphic of how I do it now:

[image]

Is this a good way of storing payment information in the `MethodOfPaiement`, depending on the `MethodOfPaiement.value` (type of payment), while satisfying 5th NF?

It doesn't look right to me. How to I get that to be in the 5th NF?

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Splitting tables for subtypes has nothing to do with DB normalization. Why do you think it does & how are you stuck answering this? What design method reference are you following & how/where are you stuck & why? [help]

Answer (score -2):

I didn't understand if for a `capitalIncrease`, several `investmentMethod`s are allowed or not. So, I tell my opinion for both cases:

1. Every `capitalIncrease` uses only one `investmentMethod`:
   you need just one table:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE public.capitalIncrease (
        id serial4 NOT NULL,
        investment_method investment_method_types,
        investment_properties jsonb
    );
   ```
2. In case several `investmentMethod`s are available for a single `capitalIncrease`, you need just two tables and a foreign key:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE capitalIncrease (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
   );

    CREATE TABLE investmentMethod (
        id serial4 NOT NULL,
        investment_method investment_method_types,
        capitalIncrease_id in4 not null,
        investment_properties jsonb
    );
    ALTER TABLE investmentMethod 
    ADD CONSTRAINT capitalIncrease_fk FOREIGN KEY (capitalIncrease_id) 
    REFERENCES capitalIncrease(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
   ```

To sum up, when you have various fields for each method, it's better to use `jsonb`. For investment methods, use enumeration.

Another suggestion, for name of tables and fields, use snake case as stated in [here](https://dev.to/ovid/database-naming-standards-2061).

Comment: The schema is simplified, CapitalIncrease contains more columns.
The question is only about InvesmentMethods, which can contains multiple MethodOfPaiment.

Comment: I understand, don't these two tables satisfy your needs?